# Django REST asks for CSRF token even with TokenAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a server for both mobile and web environments and I want to have session auth alongside with token auth. However, these seem to be at odds with each other. 
I have a different view for logins in both schemes.

If I log in as a user inside the browsable API and then send a request for token login for a different user, the server complains that there is no CSRF token. However if I log out, suddenly there's no problem.

I am not sure how severe it will be after frontend is implemented and the logins come from different devices, but so far it doesn't look good.

Any idea how to stop requiring CSRF token if the correct `Authorization: Token <token>` header is passed? Or different solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you share some code? Are you logging in via the browsable API views provided by DRF or did you write your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default `SessionAuthentication` backend from DRF is built in a way that if you provide valid session in request, it will turn on CSRF validation. There are 2 possible solutions for that: either don't use two authentications method together (don't use token when you are sending valid session cookie in request) or prioritize token authentication by putting `TokenAuthentication` backend above `SessionAuthentication` in `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: Thanks, changing the order of auth classes did indeed work as far as I can tell.