# Django CSRF Token not validated despite inheriting Generic View and CSRF middleware

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, csrf, django-csrf

I have a POST request on a DRF view that inherits `generics.CreateAPIView` and CSRF enabled in middleware, but despite that it doesn't validate my CSRF token, I am not sure why not ?

Here's my View:

```
class SchemeView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SchemeModel.objects.get_queryset()
    serializer_class = SchemeModelGraphSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            ----Business Logic Code -----
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response("Error: %s" % (e), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = {
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'RMS.middleware.AuthTokenMiddleware'
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'RMS.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

CSRF Settings:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

Using React for FE, Django for BE, `CSRF Cookies` does get sent along with request to Django server.

I tried changing CSRF cookie value, but Django silently ignores it.

**Note**: Some had suggested that along with Token auth, CSRF isn't needed. But I don't understand the reason why ?

Also, not using CSRF with Token Auth, doesn't provide a solution to Django ignoring CSRF validation. I am more curious as why doesn't it get validated ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are using `TokenAuthentication` but not `SessionAuthentication`.

`SessionAuthentication` is built in a way that if you provide valid session in request, it will turn on CSRF validation.

Never the less I will recommend you to only use 2 Authentication methods if you really believe that's needed, as it may needlessly complicate your project.

if you do choose to use both them. consider checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389240/3857837)